# Robot Framework and Python - Check if file exists

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a command line tool that exports a text file named exportedfile.txt to location C:\Temp in Windows system and the idea would be to check whether the exported file exists after the tool has been run.

If run directly in Windows environment having Robot Framework and Python, this example below works:

**Working solution on Windows environment:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${filePath}     C:\\Temp\\exportedfile.txt

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
    Check File Exists

*** Keywords ***
Check File Exists
    File Should Exist   ${filePath}
```

**Problem happening in Linux/Windows environment run as containers:**

However since in the actual environment, Robot Framework is run as a container with Linux as host but the tool exporting the text file gets run in Windows container, above solution results to this since it tries to find the file on Linux instead:

```
File '/robot/C:\Temp\exportedfile.txt' does not exist.
```

**Attempted solution with Robot Framework and Python:**

Tried to do this with a combination of Robot Framework and a custom Python library like below:

**file.py**

```
import os
from robot.api import logger

def file_exists(file):
    logger.info("Checking if file exists".format(), also_console=True)
    return os.path.isfile(file)
```

**suite.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../../../libraries/tools/file.py

*** Test Cases ***
Playground
    Test File Exists

*** Keywords ***
Test File Exists
    ${fileExists}=    File Exists    suite.robot
    Run Keyword If    ${fileExists}    Log To Console    File Exists!
```

At first I actually tried to check whether the test case file "suite.robot" itself exists just to see that this combination works.

The result is currently that when I check Robot log it shows as passed but for keyword "Test File Exists" it can be seen there that `${fileExists} = False` so for some reason this test case file itself it not seen as existing like it should in my opinion.

In the actual version I would want to check whether C:\Temp\exportedfile.txt exists (I can already manually see that the file gets exported by the command line tool).

Comment: If the robot file is running on a Linux machine, it can only check it's own filesystem. How do you expect it to see the filesystem of a windows machine?

Comment: I actually got "File Should Exist" from SSHLibrary to work now. Tested that when filename was different than specified in Robot's variable for file path the keyword failed but passed when file name matched the one specified for variable. Tried this already yesterday when I noticed that a keyword with same name from OperatingSystem library tried to look for the file on Linux instead but for some reason that SSHLibrary keyword did not work yesterday. Could be that I had the file accidentally named as txt.txt extension instead of just .txt or something like that with manually generated file.